# Why does the ghost call the victims?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-ring

Is there any significance for the phone call (The "seven days" reminder call from the ghost) in [The Ring](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0298130/)?

Most of the signs the victims saw/experienced after watching the video, like the wet hair, flies, blood, dark water, medical electrode sensors etc. were somehow related to the ghost when she was alive/dying.

But what about the phone call, why did the ghost *call* them?

Comment: There is no need for adding the movie title into the question title (as it is already in the tags and the question body) and you should refrain from it if it hidners the reading flow. See the [respective meta discussion](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1087/49) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

I found this explanation on the net.

The main cause of this whole act of Samara was to get heard. By whom!! By everyone. She was neglected her whole life. Nobody loves her. Every close person (her adoptive parents and her biological mother) can sense evil in her, so they avoided her. But she wanted to get noticed. The reason behind those videos and killings was to tell everyone that she existed and how her adoptive mother killed her.

So to spread her story she wanted that video to get spread. That is why she is giving people options. Option 1: spread the video, copy it, show it to others (we can see it in the end when Naomi figured it out); Option 2: If you failed to spread it you'll die. And Samara allowed them only 7 days as she was alive in the well for 7 days after her mother pushed her. So the phone ring is **something like "your countdown begins", basically to inform them that you have to do something after watching this video**. Samara has no other way to interact with them.

The explanation was based on the English version.

[(My theory: Samara was a very tech-loving evil. She used *video* to kill people. She used *TV* to scare them. That's why she chose *phone*, another machine, to spread fear. :) Just kidding]

Answer (score 1):

I took the name of the movie to have a dual meaning. Obviously, the tag line of the movie states ***Before you die, you see*** *The Ring*. A more obtuse meaning to me is, *Before you die, you* ***hear*** *The Ring*. I have never seen the movie [Ringu](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0178868/?ref_=nv_sr_1), but it seems from other people's descriptions of it (that this remake of that movie) was pretty close, I would have to assume it played out the same way with the telephone calls.

I have not found anything to back this up, but it seems like this could be a reason (if not *the* reason) it was chosen for the one week catalyst.

Comment: While the plot of the original might be very close to this one (including the phone call), I'm not sure the dual meaning works in *Japanese* at all, not every language calls a phone ring a "ring".

Comment: If i am not wrong then the poster used well's circular structure as the ring not a phone ring.

Comment: @AnkitSharma ... with all due respect, did you not read my post? Yes, the primary meaning of "the ring" was the well. What I was pointing out was a more obtuse meaning as I suggested. Yet another meaning of the title could be how everything has to come full circle in order (new copy of the video tape) to overcome the curse. A word (or title, in this case) can have more than one meaning.